# Magento 2.2.5 styles-m.css and styles-l.css not load

Tags: magento2, css, less, less-css, less-compilation

I'm working with new project and editing front-end css (working with less files), everything goes well but suddenly styles-m.css and styles-l.css in front-end not loading. Any ideas why this happened to me and how to solve this problem?

Comment: after copy vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/web dir to my custom theme working fine ..

Answer (score 2):

I found a problem. The problem was that I made a syntax mistake in less file. So grunt didn't compiled these files.